# Design a thread-safe Hit Counter

Tags: c#, asynchronous, hitcounter

I have designed a Hit Counter which can conveniently be used to design a Rate Limiter
Original question: https://leetcode.com/problems/design-hit-counter/

To make it thread safe, I used [lock statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/statements/lock).

```
public class HitCounter {
  private readonly int DURATION = 300;
  private readonly int[] hits, times;
  //https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/statements/lock
  private readonly Object _lockObj = new Object();
  public HitCounter() {
    times = new int[DURATION];
    hits = new int[DURATION];
  }

  public void Hit(int timestamp) {
    var idx = timestamp % DURATION;
    lock (_lockObj){
      if(times[idx] != timestamp){
        times[idx] = timestamp;
        hits[idx] = 1;
      }else{
        hits[idx]++;
      }
    }
  }

  public int GetHits(int timestamp) {
    var res = 0;
    lock (_lockObj){
      for(var i = 0; i < DURATION; ++i){
        if(timestamp - times[i] < DURATION){
          res += hits[i];
        }
      }
    }
    return res;
  }
}
```

My questions are:

- Is it just about surrounding the part which the two arrays are accessed with locks
- Isn't it better to use ConcurrentDictionary as an index-array?

Any insight is appreciated.

Comment: IMHO should have asked on https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Agree with @RandRandom - CR is probably better place to review your working code. Note that bot SO and CR require questions to be self-contained (unlike the current state of this one where reader is expected to read some external resource)... Note that one shouldn't tag posts with competition meta-tags like "leetcode" https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/399117/we-need-to-de-leet-leetcode.